# How to make agent in AnyLogic moveTo() in a order?

Tags: anylogic

Hi I am building a model that requires agent to move locations in a sequence.
I used the for loop to iterate all of required locations.
However, the result is ridiculous. The agent is heading direct to the final destination and ignores my order.

How do I fix it?

I tried multiple ways, using isMoving() for indicating if the agent reaches the point, but isMoving always returns true once the process starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to understand that a moveTo needs to be finished before doing a new one, you can't just do a bunch of moveTo instructions together and expect anylogic to guess what you meant.

So these are the steps
1 create a list in which you define all the destinations in the order that you want
2 go to the first item in the list and use moveTo
3 when the agent arrives to the destination (using statecharts and transition triggered by arrival to destination) remove the first item on the list
4 if there's nothing else in the list, do nothing or return home, otherwise, go back to 2